# How to subtract from only specific elements of a list

Tags: r, list, lapply, subtraction

Ok so I have a list (named "datalist") with 829 elements. The numbers in each element are on a scale of 1 to 676, yet my code cycles back to the beginning of the 676 when the element is a vector of length greater than one. I'm looking for a way to subtract 676 from only the values of the list that are greater than 676. Ive tried using lapply to no avail. Below is a small section of the list followed by my code and error message. Thank you!

```
[[825]]
[1] 429 496

[[826]]
[1] 8 895 1181

[[827]]
[1] 6

[[828]]
[1] 901 916 1298 1299 1302 1307
```

Code:

```
sub <- function(x){
 for(i in datalist[x]){
  if(i > 676)
   i = i-676
 }
}

lapply(1:829, sub)
```

The code returns all of the list elements as NULL and gives the following error message.

Error Message:

```
1-50: In if (i > 676) i = i - 676 :
 the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What i'm looking for is to have the code output:

```
[[825]]
[1] 429 496

[[826]]
[1] 8 219 505

[[827]]
[1] 6

[[828]]
[1] 225 240 622 623 626 631
```

Comment: Not quite I believe.

Comment: Oh I see - you're not 'subtracting (i.e. removing) from the list' - you're 'subtracting from each element of the list'

Comment: I think you can still make use of the answers on the other question though.

Comment: Alright will check out! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sub <- function(x) {x[x > 676] <- x[x > 676] - 676}
lapply(datalist, sub)
```

Also, if all values greater than 676 are less than 2*676, sub can be:

```
sub <- function(x) {x %% 676} #returns modulo
```

Comment: Unfortunately, some values are more than 2*676. Using that script outputs all values less than 676 as "integer(0)"

Comment: The second "sub" worked!